# Is the torus with one hole homeomorphic to the torus with two holes?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, connectedness

I would like to understand why the torus with one hole is not homeomorphic to the torus with two holes.

I have a very basic understanding of the concepts (I know what an homeomorphism is but not much more).

My idea is that a torus with one hole can be disconnected by two loops, whereas the torus with two holes may not be disconnected by two loops.

Is this argument correct? Can it me formalized (even the part on connectedness).

Or maybe there is better argument

Comment: Your idea is ok. Formally you should convince yourself that these objects have different homeomorphic invariants. For example you could consider the fundamental group. It is generated by two cycles for the torus with one hole and by more than two for the torus with two holes. Start by drawing a picture!

Comment: Your idea is perfect, though it needs some refinement. The torus with two holes can actually be disconnected by a single curve (can you find it?). You want to consider what are called non-separating curves — curves that don’t immediately cut the surface into separate pieces.

Comment: @James I don't know what the fundamental group is, and I think it is outside the scope of the class I follow.

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:** The following argument should be taken loosely, and not as a proof. It assumes the [classification of surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Classification_of_closed_surfaces) (which is silly).

For the sake of getting some contradiction, let $f:S_1\to S_2$ be a homeomorphism. Here, $S_1$ is the one-holed torus and $S_2$ is the two-holed torus.

Now, define a *non-separating curve* $\gamma$ on a surface $S$ to be a curve such that $S\setminus\gamma$ is still connected.

Let $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ be the two most popular curves on $S_1$ that cut the torus into a disk. Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, the image of these curves under $f$ (i.e. $f(\gamma_1)$ and $f(\gamma_2)$) must also cut $S_2$ into a disk. Now, I claim that $f(\gamma_1)$ and $f(\gamma_2)$ must also be non-separating in $S_2$. This is a good exercise to stew on by yourself!

Moreover, I claim that no pair of non-separating curves can cut $S_2$ into a disk. To prove this, you pick your favorite pair of non-separating curves on $S_2$, and cut along them. Show this is not a disk. Then, for any other pair of non-separating curves $\alpha_i$, there is a homeomorphism taking the $\alpha_i$ curves to your favorite curves. Thus, cutting along the $\alpha_i$ curves cannot yield a disk.

However, from earlier we know that $f(\gamma_i)$ must cut $S_2$ into a disk, thus obtaining our contradiction.

Comment: Thanks you for your detailed explanations. However I have a hard time trying to figure out those popular curves. Are they the two loops that "generate" the torus? To me they cut the torus into a disc with a hole and a cylindre.

Comment: These curves are the blue and red curves in [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Simple_torus_with_cycles.svg). Let me know if these makes things more clear!

Comment: Ok these are indeed the curves I was refering to as "generating" the torus (I guess this is not the correct vocabulary). However I still cannot see why they cut the torus into a disk...

Comment: People do use that vocabulary to refer to those curves, but usually within the context of the fundamental group. I just wanted to be explicit. You can cut the torus in steps. What do you get if you cut along just the red curve?

Comment: Oh ok I get it, you need to cut along both! (sorry, English isn't my first language).

Comment: Yes you do! Sorry if that wasn't clear from my explanation. Any time I say "cut along curve**s**," I mean that you consider the surface $S\setminus(\bigcup\gamma_i)$ for the curves $\gamma_i$.

Comment: "for any other pair of non-separating curves $\alpha_i$": presumably we must also require that the $\alpha_i$ are in general position and meet in a single point, like the $\gamma_i$ (since there other possibilities for a pair of non-separating curves which are not equivalent under a homeomorphism). Even with this requirement, how exactly do we check all such pairs $\alpha_i$, of which there quite a variety?

Comment: @HewWolff Oh, right. I completely blanked out on the intersection piece. I realized that I'm implicitly using one-half of the classification of surfaces here when I talk about curves going to other curves, so most of this argument is silly. Perhaps this should be taken as some intuition as opposed to a proof (which this is not).

Comment: @tiintin A real satisfactory proof of this fact would use a few technical details which it seems may be outside the scope of your course. That said, I would strongly encourage you to seek these details out. They (read: the *fundamental group* and *homology*) are the bread-and-butter of many argument surrounding surfaces -- $n$-holed tori. A fantastic opportunity would be to work through [this explanation of the classification of surfaces](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/surfclass-n.pdf) with a faculty member at your institution.

Answer (score 2):

One of these has $H^1(\Sigma_1,\Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z^2$ and the other $H^1(\Sigma_2,\Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z^4$.

In general the $g$-holed torus $\Sigma_g$ has $H^1(\Sigma_g,\Bbb Z)\cong \Bbb Z^{2g}$.

One can see this by considering a representative loop for each of the $2g$-homotopy classes on the $g$-holed torus, and cutting along these, and by homeomorphism taking any pair of such cut surfaces to one another.

---

Informally you can simply fix a base-point for loops to start and end at. On the $1$-holed torus $\Sigma_1$ there are two topologically distinct types of loops. Those that go 'through' the hole, and those that go around the torus. Similarly on the $2$-holed torus, there are $4$ different types of generating loops, either going 'around' each hole, or through it.

These generating loops all contribute $1$ rank to $H^1(\Sigma_g,\Bbb Z)$. So really there is nothing scary about this.

Comment: I don't understand the notations, and I am looking for a formal proof using basic concepts. I don't know what an homotopy class is.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a figure $8$ as the intersection of a plane with the torus with two holes but not with the one with only one hole.

Comment: Ok I get the idea, could you please develop it formally?

Answer (score 0):

I like your basic idea, but I would make it more precise as follows: in a two-holed torus, you can cut along two disjoint circles and leave the space still connected; in a one-holed torus, you cannot do this.

The first part is pretty easy and I think you have already found such circles.

So why can't we do this in a one-holed torus? Here I am going to wave my hands a little.

There are basically two kinds of circles in a torus. The trivial kind is just a little circle that cuts out a disk. To see the other kind, look at the torus as a unit square with the left and right edges glued together, and the top and bottom edges glued together (look up "flat torus" for more). Now draw a line starting at the lower left corner and going up and to the right with a slope of (say) $1/2$. This will end up going twice around the horizontal axis and once around the vertical axis before it comes back to the lower left, giving us a circle. You can do this for any slope $p/q$, including the special slope $\infty$ that goes straight up. The "favorite" choices of circle correspond to $\infty$ (vertical) and $0$ (horizontal); try drawing $3/5$ for a more interesting one.

The key thing here is that, up to a homeomorphism of the torus, those circles I just described are *all* the circles. This is not easy to prove (algebraic topology was invented to answer questions like this) but it should seem plausible if you experiment.

Assuming that's true, how would we find two disjoint circles in the torus which do not disconnect it? Clearly neither of the circles can be trivial, so they both have that $p/q$ form. In fact they must have the same slope: the first one cuts the torus into a cylinder, and the second one cuts that cylinder into two cylinders.

This shows that the two circles must always disconnect the torus, so you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain to me why two non intersecting circles in the $2$-holed torus cannot be mapped to two intersecting circle in the $1$-holed torus?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about intersecting versus nonintersecting circles, but the idea here is that in the two-holed torus there _is_ a pair of circles with a certain property, and in the one-holed torus there _is no_ such pair. You don't actually have to worry about how to map one to the other, because if there was a homeomorphism, anything that happens in the two-holed torus must also happen in the one-holed torus.